# HTML link to picture in subfolder

Tags: html

I know how to link a picture to a website using src="image.jpg", but I recently got a free web server and I put my pictures in the same folder as my homepage.html but the pictures aren't loading. Why is this? I have also tried changing the link to "./public_html/photos/image.jpg" but it still doesn't work. Have I done something wrong? Thanks

Comment: Where is the image located exactly? Is it in the same folder as `index.html` or is it actually in a folder called `photos`? paths in HTML are relative to the HTML's file location

Comment: it it in a folder called photos which is a subdirectory

Comment: Thanks everyone. Got it to work eventually. Collaborative effort. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change src="image.jpg" with this:

```
src="photos/image.jpg"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one:

```
src="images/image.jpg";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put full link of your website link.

```
src="https://example.com/images/image.jpg";
```

Comment: This is bad practice really.

Comment: Just for testing purpose only.

Comment: So, testing purpose is example.com as per OP ?

Answer (score 0):

Some **technique** is to try to open your image via browser, just only to check if path & image are accessible in public.

Append the path/image_file in your 000webhost.com host, most likely:

```
http://000webhost.com/photos/image.jpg
```

If you open it, you can use the path to image source like:

```
/photos/image.jpg
or
photos/image.jpg
```